# Disable child viewPager swipe inside parent viewPager

Tags: android, android-viewpager, touch-event

I want to disable swipe of child viewpager which is in a parent viewpager.

I currently use this custom child viewpager

```
public class CustomViewPager extends ViewPager {

public CustomViewPager(Context context) {
    super(context);
}

public CustomViewPager(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}

@Override
public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    // Never allow swiping to switch between pages
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    // Never allow swiping to switch between pages
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {

    return true;
}
}
```

This disable swipe of child viewpager,but the parent viewpager swiping get disabled at that portion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should return false from both `onInterceptTouchEvent` and `onTouchEvent` in the child ViewPager. Returning True from onTouchEvent will tell the parent that the view has handled the event successfully, which is not what you want.

```
@Override
public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    // Never allow swiping to switch between pages
    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    // Never allow swiping to switch between pages
    return false;
}
```

Comment: but the parent viewpager have a scrollview.onInterceptTouchEvent return true make scrollview not wrking

Comment: In that case you should return false from onTouchEvent from the Child ViewPager. I have modified my answer

Answer (score 5):

To disable ViewPager scrolling without affecting parent Events, override canScrollHorizontally() method:

```
@Override
    public boolean canScrollHorizontally(int direction) {
        //Disable horizontal scrolling
        if (enabled) {
            return super.canScrollHorizontally(direction);
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
```